# Meaning of -nt operator in shell script (zsh completion)

Tags: shell, operators, zsh, completion

I stumbled upon a Z shell (`zsh`) completion file, and I can't figure out what the `-nt` operator does.

```
if ! [ -r $cache -a -s $cache ] || [ "$squeezy" -nt $cache ]
```

What is the explanation? Is this even a valid operator, or is it rather a typo by the author?

Here is the whole file:

```
#compdef squeezy

local squeezy=`whence -p squeezy`
local cache="$HOME/.squeezy_zsh_completion_cache"

[ -z "$squeezy" ] && return 1
[ -x "$squeezy" ] || return 2

if ! [ -r $cache -a -s $cache ] || [ "$squeezy" -nt $cache ]
then
   command squeezy -options | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '^-[a-zA-Z0-9]' > $cache
fi

[ -r $cache -a -s $cache ] || return 4

_arguments `cat $cache`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `man zshall` and searching for `-nt` shows:

> ```
> file1 -nt file2
> ```
>
> true if `file1` exists and is newer than `file2`.